# It is secure do accounts just with web3.eth.accounts.create() ? (entropy)

Tags: web3js, security, accounts

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');

let url = 'infuralink';
let web3 = new Web3(url);
console.log(web3.eth.accounts.create());
```

This is the code of many tutorials for do a key pair.
it is completely secure or do I need to pass a parameter to have enough entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is secure. If you don't pass entropy to it, it will use [randomhex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomhex), see [Web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-accounts.html#parameters). That uses the secure `crypto.randomBytes` function which is [pretty secure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033592/5887673). It's just a wrapper around `OpenSSL's RAND_bytes()`.